# Oops! Something Bad Happened! - Allow Refresh (F5) to redirect to/reload the non-error page

Tags: feature-request, error-message, user-experience

I just got an `Oops! Something Bad Happened!` error, while opening [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452065/com-jcraft-jsch-jschexception-verify-false). This question works now, it was only a temporary problem.

However, when this happens, you get redirected to [this URL](https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/31452065/com-jcraft-jsch-jschexception-verify-false). From there, you can't hit F5 (refresh) to try to reload the question. You have to find and open the original link to the question again.

It would be nice, if the URL would not be altered, so that F5 works (or a refresh of the error page tries to redirect to the original question, if available).

Comment: On MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307294/sub-optimal-500-error-redirection

Comment: the new URL contains the most important part of the original URL, so there's not much to find.

Comment: If that " most important part of the original URL" is displayed on page somewhere, that will be great. Very few will try to read the URL to find the source.

Comment: Yes, at least put a link on the error page so I don't have to copy the URL from the error URL and paste. Bad user experience.

Comment: @Pang, but that is marked as a duplicate, and the dupe target is deferred (postponed indefinitely I guess?)

Comment: Happened to me yesterday too.  I wasn't paying attention to the URL, so I didn't realize it had even changed and thought the site was broken for about 20 minutes until I finally noticed it.

Comment: Seems to have been fixed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385882/377214

Answer (score 1):

I find this quite a nice solution, especially when contention problems occur, as people will usually hit refresh with a passion when they see errors like this, which only help in increasing the factors leading to the problem.

Making it easy for people to get back to the failing url, i.e. by deleting the `/error?aspxerrorpath=` part from the URL helps both parts: it makes people more conscious that there is a problem by redirecting them again to the error page if the problem occurs, and makes ignorant people requests go away my making them endless refresh requests no-op operations.

Comment: Does making users back off actually help for the majority of problems?

Comment: This sounds like sacrificing usability to solve a purely technical problem... Throttling requests if necessary is a much better solution in that case.

Comment: Sometime we have given this type of solution for clients when we are in deadline