# Provide the ability to go back to page if there was an unexpected error

Tags: feature-request, error-message

Today I hit "Refresh" in my browser when viewing a question and got an error message:

[image: Error message page with no ability to go back]

The error itself seems to have been something trivial as the site was up and I could still otherwise access the question. Whatever it was, it seems it was inconsequential but there was no way to go back to the initial page aside from modifying the URL.

It's a rather minor annoyance, true, but I don't see a good reason *not* to allow going back to the page. Worse case scenario, there is still an error and the user just gets the same screen again. But the issue might not reappear.

A user would likely try to re-visit the page *anyway*, so this would be a really (*really*) minor Quality of Life improvement.

One option is to [Allow Refresh (F5) to redirect to/reload the non-error page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363741/oops-something-bad-happened-allow-refresh-f5-to-redirect-to-reload-the-non) but my proposal is one step more generic and leave it to the discretion of the SO team. They might prefer to show this page instead of always navigating back, so people are encouraged to report the issue. So, I think having a link on the error screen that leads back to the question is another acceptable possibility. Perhaps there are other options I've not thought about that would still allow a return to the initial page that ran into an error.

Comment: @ivarni I would agree this is one solution. It's exactly what I initially tried, actually. However, I would also be content with a button or a link on the error screen that links back. I don't want to impose a concrete solution, so I'd say mine is the more generic proposal.